# View Google Chrome History

Tags: computer-forensics

I'm doing some digital forensic investigation. I'm wondering how I can view the history of google chrome by registry ?, I tried to navigate to \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome but I didn't found any google history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome stores the data in a **sqlite database** which you can find here:

*Location of Google Chrome history*

**Windows XP**

C:\Documents and Settings<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

C:\Documents and Settings<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

**Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10**

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

**Mac OS X**

/Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

/Users//Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache

**Linux/Unix**

/home//.config/google-chrome/Default

/home//.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache

Alternatively you can use the **[ChromeHistoryView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html)** program from Nir Soft.